# How can I know if there is a new update of SDK Platform Tools?

Tags: android, adb, updates, fastboot

I am not a code developer but am a IT expert.
I want to know how can I stay up-to-date on Android SDK platform tools over Windows without installing the whole Android Studio, because I just need adb and fastboot.
Also I don't want to go all months to Android SDK Platform Tools release notes page to check if there is a new release available. Is there a way to have a notification or something similar when a new release comes to air?
Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/tools/sdkmanager

Comment: You can set up an Android repo in Github in which you define dependencies to the platform tools via Gradle, and then you can use Dependabot to automatically create PRs for you when one of those dependencies have a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
sdkmanager --update [options]
```

periodically to get the updates for all the installed packages.

Check `--help` for other options.

Comment: Is the command-line sdkmanager version still included in recent versions of Android SDK?

Comment: I can't use sdkmanager because I have platform-tools and sdkmanager.exe is not included